# Is there a way to make your bot copy messages to another channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord

The problem is that i wrote some code, which i think is correct, but obviously it is not correct, so i want to ask you guys, because you could know better

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == bot.user:
        print(message.author,message.content)
        return


    print(message.author,message.content)

    channel = bot.get_channel(576705173766930433)
    await channel.send('{0.author}: {0.message}'.format(message))
```

when i send a message, the console will oppose with this:
Ignoring exception in on_message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 255, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Servant_Of_Paschen.py", line 38, in on_message
    await channel.send('{0.author}: {0.message}'.format(message))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys i found out alone

```
await channel.send('{}: {}'.format(message.author, message.content))
```

is think i wanted to do